# Castle Windsor assembly versioning and MSTest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, mstest

We have a solution that relies on Castle Windsor with some projects referencing 3.0 and some 3.1.

The tests need Windsor 3.1, but the final project to be built references 3.0, which means that it the last version copied into the OutDir folder.  This results in all our tests failing in MSTest but not locally.

Is there any way to force the tests to run using the 3.1 versions or will we need to update all projects in the solution?

Comment: Are you placing the targetted dll version in the assembly ref within the csproj?

Comment: Yeah, we're using NuGet packages to manage references and the reference in the test projects points to the 3.1 assembly.

Comment: As long as both, product and test dlls have the right version stamped on the reference you should be able to drop the 3.1 dlls in as deployment items for your tests and install the 3.0 dlls which can be picked up for your product?